# ul is moving out of div when resizing browser screen size

Tags: html, css, resize, html-lists

I've made a header that includes a img on the left and an ul or the right. When I resize my screen (to where the borders of the img and ul meet) the ul  jumps out of the div. I want my browser to just give me a horizontal scroll bar instead of resizing.

NOTE: I'm not worried about making this site responsive.

HTML

```
 <header><img src="images/logo.gif">
    <ul>
    <li>Toll Free USA & Canada: 8002452719 Australia: 1800 645437</li>
    <li>Other Countries: + 86 773 583 5179</li>
    <li>contact@chinaculturetour.com</li>
    </ul>
   </header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: tomato;
    padding: 3px 263px 0;
}

header > img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0;
}

header > ul {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: share a fiddle please

Comment: use a wrapper, encapsulate <header> and the <ul> in their own divs and put them in the wrapper, and give the div containing the <ul> overflow: scroll;

Comment: I figured it out. It had to do with not setting a min-width.